# How can I remove the base address from an assigned url in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, mern

How can I remove the base body URL from an component.
For Clear, Please see the screenshot
[complete URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy9wR.png)
[code page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Y7c.png)

from the complete URL, we can see that it has address http://localhost/admin/app/https:...news address but I want that it had only https:....news address which is opened in new tab.
How can I do that(I cannot use a tag instead of Link)

Comment: I am using browser router as well

Comment: Dont use relative url, like use in this way `fetch("https://")` not like this `fetch("/https://")`

Comment: Basically, I am getting the response from NEWS API and I assigned the link of News to the React Link but when I open the link by browser or taping to React Link, I get the https://localhost:3000/news_url  (this is invalid news URL) instead of this, I want when I tap the React Link From Frontend, the News will open in a New tab(means the base address or http:localhost/ should be removed)

Comment: `onClick={window.open(
                    url,
                    "_blank"
                  )}` I think you want something like this?

Comment: Can Explain, what is the problem when I used this:                                                       
<Link to= {{pathname: url}} color="inherit" underline="hover"  component={RouterLink} target = "_blank">

Comment: Has my above solution is worked or not?

Comment: No, More Error occurred,

Comment: Let me give you one example in codesandbox

Comment: Here is the example, please look https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-colden-g6m2td?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

If you knew that you will get an absolute URL from the database then please don't use the `Link` tag.

Github: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/1147

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-colden-g6m2td?file=/src/App.js

Example: https://g6m2td.csb.app

You will see a clear difference here.